# Determine coordinates for $p=7-12t-8t^2+12t^3$ in another basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $S=\{1,2t,-2+4t^2,-12t+8t^3\}$ be a set of polynomials in $P_3$.
>   Show that these polynomials make up a basis for $P_3$ and determine
>   the coordinates for $p=7-12t-8t^2+12t^3$ in this basis.

The first part of the problem was easy, showing that they make up a basis by showing that the polynomials are linearly independant and since $\dim(P_3)=\dim(S)=4,$ they can span $P_3$.

But how do I determine the coordinates for $p=7-12t-8t^2+12t^3$ in this basis?

Comment: As with your prior question, just match coefficients.  Hint:  the multiplier of the last one has to be $\frac {12}8$ to match the coefficient of $t^3$ and the multiplier of the third must be $-2$ to match the coefficient of $t^2$.

Comment: But I've already solved the first part as per your instructions in my prevous question. This question also asks me to find coordinates for that polynomial in theat particular basis.

Comment: Yes, that's what finding these coefficients will do.  This time, don't forget, you are solving $a\times 1 +b\times (2t)+ c\times (-2+4t^2)+d\times (-12t+8t^3)=7-12t-8t^2+12t^3$.  I claimed in my hint that it is obvious that $d=\frac {12}8$ and $c=-2$ but you should check those claims, and find $a,b$.

Comment: @Parseval Note that solve the system directly is completely equivalent to work by the $M$ matrix. Of course, if you can see by inspection what some coefficient is the direct method could be more effective but if the relation is complex with $M$ matrix the set up if faster.

Comment: @lulu - okay that was not hard. But I don't intuitivly understand why I have to do this. I'd appreciate it if you can bother explaining why this works.

Comment: But this is just what spanning and dependence mean.  If a vector $\vec w$ is in the span of $\{\vec v_i\}$ that means that we can find coefficients $\lambda_i$ with $\vec w = \sum \lambda_i \vec {v_i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

As a general method

- write the matrix $M$ from the basis S to the standard basis; M has for columns the component of the basis vectors with respect to the standard basis, that is

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2&0\\0&2&0&-12\\0&0&4&0\\0&0&0&8 \end{bmatrix}$$

- then if $v_S$ is  a vector in the $S$ basis we have $v=Mv_S$ where $v$ is expressed in the standard basis
- then $v_s=M^{-1}v$

Comment: determinate not equal to 0 and use equivalence relation in linear algebra(to rank or something you prefer) then done.

Comment: @JC Sorry, I don't understand your point,

Comment: Same as your argument just towards some context with the class.(These days we learn a list of equivalent relation and this is one of those application.)

Comment: @JC Sorry but I don't get your observation, note that the determinant is $\neq 0$ since $S$ is a basis.

Comment: $det(A)\neq 0\rightarrow Rank(A)=4$ and $S$ linear independent set in $P_3$ where $P_3$ was a 4 dimension space, by theorem $S$ span $P_3$, so in general the solution was based on the argument of the rank of $M$ (number of linear independent vectors) but not $det(M)$ itself

Comment: Awesome @gimusi !!

Comment: @Parseval Well done! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_0=1$, $p_1=2t$, $p_2=4t^2-2$, and $p_3=8t^3-12t$ be the basis vectors.  For $p=12t^3-8t^2-12t+7$, it's convenient to note first that

$$2p-3p_3=(24t^3-16t^2-24t+14)-(24t^3-36t)=-16t^2+12t+14$$

From there you can see that

$$2p-3p_3+4p_2=(-16t^2+12t+14)+(16t^2-8)=12t+6$$

Can you see how to continue?